# Sending GET request using Postman for Array of objects

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongoose

I am trying to send GET Request for my node rest API which consist of Array of Objects for 'products subCategory'. I am stucked on how to achieve this. Here is my schema for products and it's subCategory:

```
    const subSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    tshirt: {
      type: Boolean,
    },

    mobile: {
        type: Boolean,

    },
    laptop: {
        type: Boolean,

    },

  });


const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: { type: String, },
    price: { type: Number, },
    quantity: { type: Number, },
    mainCategory: { type: String, },
    subCategory: [subSchema]

});
```

And this is how I have defined 'Controller' for fetching the products by SubCategory:

```
  exports.products_get_bySubCategory = (req, res, next) => {
  Product
  .find({subCategory: req.params.subCategory })
  .exec()
  .then(docs => {
    const response = {
      count: docs.length,
      products: docs
    };
    res.status(200).json(response);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({
      error: err
    });
  });
};
```

This is how I am trying to access products from URL:

http://localhost:5000/products/subCategory/

Kindly help me achieve the proper way to GET products byCategory.

[sample data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0231f.png)

Comment: When you try to access the resource **http://localhost:5000/products/subCategory/** do you see any error in Postman or in Nodejs console?

Comment: @ddsultan yes. `{
"error": {
"message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"subCategory\" at path \"_id\" for model \"Product\"",
"name": "CastError",
"stringValue": "\"subCategory\"",
"kind": "ObjectId",
"value": "subCategory",
"path": "_id"
}
}`   This is what I get

Comment: I have tried the code above without any data in the database assuming that you are not passing any parameters (e.g. `null`, `{}` or `undefined`) in your GET request and it gives me empty array back.

Comment: Basically if you can help me out in defining the endpoints for array of objects in this subcategory

Comment: Can I get your email id to share data? It is difficult for me to share here

Comment: Can you please post some **sample** data?

Comment: @ddsultan I have attached the screenshot in my question.

Comment: You have inconsistent data with your schema for your `subCategory` whereby `subCategory` should been one/all of the following: `var subCategory = { tshirt: true, mobile: false, laptop: true}; //boolean values chosen randomly` but in your screenshot the object has another property name (`upperwear`) with string value.

Comment: Do you have to use a separate schema for the `subCategory` property?

Comment: That is the sample data that I have stored for subCategory. I have to develop 3 level hierarchy for my products: mainCategory, subCategory and then subSubCategory. This is the best way I thought of, If you could suggest some other way.

Comment: `{ "error": { "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"subCategory\" at path \"_id\" for model \"Product\"", "name": "CastError", "stringValue": "\"subCategory\"", "kind": "ObjectId", "value": "subCategory", "path": "_id" } }`. You got this error most probably because the resource expects something like this: `localhost:port/products/:id`

Comment: fetching product by _id is working fine. I want to fetch (GET request) them using subCategory which contains array of objects and also I don't know how to do this with localhost:post/products/_____  URL. Like what should come in _____ subCategory or subCategory[something] or subCategory[something]/[soomething]

Comment: I am in fact not talking about if fetching `product` with `id`works or not. When you send a GET request like this: *http://localhost:5000/products/subCategory/* you get the error, `"Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"subCategory\"` Because the route expects an ID of type `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` whereas what you sending is of type *string* `subCategory`

Comment: yes. now you got it right. Please share your email to. I don't enough points to resolve this over here.

Comment: You might want to share yours since I am not sure if it is against the communty guidelines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the sample data you have provided a solution for your problem looks something like this:

```
//based on the sample: { "upperwearKey" : "upperwearValue" }
var alternativeFilter  = { subCategory:  { "$elemMatch": { upperwearKey : "upperwearValue", anotherKey: "anotherValue" } } }; //alternative with "$elemMatch"
var filter = { "subCategory.upperwearKey": "upperwearValue" }; 
    Product.find(filter)//you can also use ´alternativeFilter´ 
    .exec()
    .then(docs => {
        const response = {
        count: docs.length,
        products: docs
        };
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);      
    });
```